# T-SQL ORDER BY according to a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am writing some sort of resources management system.

A resource is an instance of a definition. A definition is the  metadata, basically it contains the properties.

This is in general my DB:

```
TypeDefinition
id    name
===============
1     CPU


PropertyDefinition
id    name       typeDefinitionId   valueType
================================================
1     frequency  1                  int
2     status     1                  string


TypeInstance
id    name     typeDefinitionId
=================================
1     CPU#1    1  
2     CPU#2    1


PropertyInstanceValue
id   propertyDefinitionId  typeInstanceId   valueType   intValue  StringValue FloatValue
========================================================================================
1    1                     1                int         10
2    2                     1                string                Pending
3    1                     2                int         20
4    2                     2                string                Approved
```

***REQUIREMENT:***

order all resources according to a **specific property value**.

For example:  order all resources according to their **status** --> Meaning CPU#2 will appear before CPU#1 because “Approved” is before “Pending”.

If we were to order according to **frequency**, CPU#1 will appear before CPU#2 because 10 is before 20.

So I need to sort each time according to a different column (intValue / stringValue/ FloatValue / etc), depending on the property's valueType.

Any suggestion?

***LIMITATION:***

PIVOT is currently the only option we've thought of, but it's not really possible since the DB is huge and I need the query to be as fast as possible.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Michal.

Comment: Post the code you have so far, and let us know where you are stuck

Comment: Looks like you have a particularily nasty form of an [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) setup.  You also have a denormalization problem, which may come back to bite you (because `valueType` is duplicated in `PropertyInstanceValue`).  You aren't going to need pivot (and would it consistently order _columns_, anyways?), this can be done with nothing but joins and some correlated result tables, so long as you write it for one column.  But are you solely interested in the _alphabetic_ order of the status, or some other criteria?

Answer (score 5):

If the problem is that you don't want to dynamically build the query then use this `order by` structure:

```
order by case @orderby
    when 'status' then status
    when 'frequency' then frequency
    end
option (recompile)
```

You will pass the `@orderby` parameter. The final `recompile` `option` is to force the engine to build a new plan according to the passed parameters, that is, assuming you are using a stored procedure.

Comment: That's a good alternative to Dynamic SQL that I didn't know about.  +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order your query results using SQL (as opposed to sorting them in the calling application after results are returned) you would need to generate Dynamic SQL and execute it using sp_executesql.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I would approach it as follows:

1. Create a table of allowed string values, making sure to include a column for specifying sorting precedence (let's call this AllowedValues)

   > create table [dbo].[AllowedStringValues] ( PropertyDefinitionId int, stringValue varchar(250), sortOrder int)
2. Create a complex subquery that selects out the proper value based on the row's PropertyDefinition (it looks like it needs to look among 3 columns depending on what datatype it is).
3. If the value is a string type, inner join the subquery with the AllowedStringValues table
     (assuming value was stored into a value column)

   > inner join AllowedStringValues on ValueType=String AND value = stringValue OR ValueType <> string
4. Sort by the sort priority in AllowedValues if it is a string, or by the numeric value otherwise.

   > order by case ValueType
   >   when 'string' then sortOrder
   >   else value
   >   end